# How do I show the contact form in panels?

Tags: 8, panels, emails

I have installed panels and Panelizer modules and used the core contact form.

There is no feature available for adding contact form in the panels.

How do I add the contact form in Panels without using the form Block module or other moudle?

Comment: If memory serves the contact form doesn’t have that functionality out of the box, so it’s impossible to do it without a module. It can be a custom module of course, doesn’t have to exist already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by creating new block type without using any contributed modules.

In Block Layout,

1. Create a new block type.
2. Add a new field and choose other in entity reference.
3. Choose Contact Form in the Types of item to reference.

then this will be used to create the entity as block.

And then the block can be assigned in the particular region in Panels.

Answer (score 1):

Please use [contact_block](https://www.drupal.org/project/contact_block), because `ctools` use blocks please see module `ctools_block` in module `ctools`.